# coolbits "missing fans" after adding Pcie splitter

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I'm working on assembling my personal computer.

The motherboard I'm using is a TB85.

I, at first, tested a 5 GPU coolbits configuration,

then I tested a 6 GPU coolbits configuration,

Both worked fine.

When I run "`nvidia-sensors`", in a terminal, it shows thermal controls and all the sliders.

also the following runs fine:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=4
let NumGPU=6
for (( n=0; n < NumGPU; n++))
do
        /usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:$n]/GPUFanControlState=1"
        /usr/bin/nvidia-settings -a "[fan:$n]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=100"
done
```

I used a 1-to-4 GPU splitter to add a 7th GPU.

I then had :

- GTX 1070
- GTX 1070
- GTX 1060
- GTX 1060
- GTX 1060
- GTX 1060
- GTX 1060

(2 GTX 1070 + 5 GTX 1060)

in this configuration "SETI@home" continues to function, however two of the gpus no longer have fan control.

```
jstateson@tb85-nvidia:~/Desktop$ nvidia-smi
Fri Jul 26 08:21:45 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.116                Driver Version: 390.116                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|100%   41C    P2   101W / 151W |   1499MiB /  8117MiB |     91%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|100%   62C    P2   121W / 120W |   1300MiB /  6078MiB |     95%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|100%   59C    P2   115W / 120W |   1292MiB /  3019MiB |     92%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|100%   64C    P2    83W / 120W |   1292MiB /  3019MiB |     93%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  GeForce GTX 1070    Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   45C    P2    85W / 151W |   1315MiB /  8119MiB |     87%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:09:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|100%   57C    P2    84W / 120W |   1292MiB /  3019MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 48%   65C    P2    60W / 120W |   1045MiB /  3019MiB |     52%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1222      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            86MiB |
|    0      1685      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          97MiB |
|    0     12951      C   ...x41p_V0.98b1_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu_cuda90  1303MiB |
|    1      1222      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             6MiB |
|    1     12922      C   ...x41p_V0.98b1_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu_cuda90  1281MiB |
|    2      1222      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             6MiB |
|    2     12917      C   ...x41p_V0.98b1_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu_cuda90  1273MiB |
|    3      1222      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             6MiB |
|    3     12944      C   ...x41p_V0.98b1_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu_cuda90  1273MiB |
|    4     12958      C   ...x41p_V0.98b1_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu_cuda90  1303MiB |
|    5      1222      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             6MiB |
|    5     12932      C   ...x41p_V0.98b1_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu_cuda90  1273MiB |
|    6     12970      C   ...x41p_V0.98b1_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu_cuda90  1033MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The `xorg.conf` looks fine and the monitor works fine but I cannot access the #4 and #6 fans as shown above.

I also noticed that the buss IDs vary 1..4 then jump to 9 and A.

I changed my `loop NumGPU` to 7 and also tried 15 but same problem.

I also noticed that at least one of the GPUs on the splitter has working fan control.

I cant tell if the 2nd one has or not as I cant make sense out of the buss ID numbers.

Before putting the splitter in, the IDs were "`0:01:0 .. 0:06:0`" which makes sense.

Maybe 18.04 and the NVIDIA 390 driver cannot cope with splitters?

When the ID was 1..6 fans were 0..5 but how do I handle the 9 and the "A"?

Comment: I have no idea about anything related to multiple GPUs, that is not my domain, however `A` seems to indicate a hexadecimal value, in which case iff the IDs count from 1 (this is unusual) and the fans count from 0 (this makes more sense), then ID `A` would correspond to fan 9 and ID `9` would correspond to fan 8. I hope I'm being relevant and helpful

Comment: Yea, I tried using 15 to get the loop to go 0..14.  I assume the argument to nvidia-settings in decimal.  Even if it was in hex the '9"  decimal should have worked as that is 9 in hex.  I am going to try A, B , etc see if that works.

Comment: Thanks to whoever re-wrote my original post, double spacing and explaining more. I have had a post re-written by a moderator before but received a tongue lashing as I had not yet figured out how the formatting codes worked.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a timing problem.  Probably cause by different GPUs and behavior of the 4-in=1 PCIe multipler and the order in which the GPUs were arranged and possibly the vendor (pny, evga, msi).

I swapped the  gtx1070 boards as the board that had a single fan was not spinning its fan fast enough and it sat in a rack where it did not not get a lot of air.  The other gtx1070 had a pair of fans and was more exposed to the large cooling fans so if it ran slow it would still run cool.  After swapping USB3 cables (all are on risers) I discovered that ALL had coolbits enabled.  Every GPU had a temp slider, but only GPU #5 was not running at %100.  I brought up nvidia-settings and it had a slider (as all now did) and I set it to %100.  I did not have to run that script a second time.

So my conclusion is that the 4-in-1 worked OK but subtle hardware differences caused the coolbits mechanism to to not get full control.  ie:  could be more robust.

[EDIT] Found info on bus ID and how to use coolbits here
[wiki archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks)

hope this helps someone else